# Custom UIView storyboard class not created in simulator, shows up in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder

I'm trying to make a custom Storyboard component that is basically a circular progress bar. I've made my custom class (called CircularProgressView) which inherits UIView. I then create a UIView in interface builder and makes it an instance of my CircualProgressView class. Everything renders as expected in Interface Builder [image: Circular Progress View in Interface Builder], but when I load the app in the simulator or in my device (iPhone 6), it's simply not there. I've tried setting breakpoints inside the functions `initWithFrame`, `initWithCoder` and `drawRect`, but no breakpoint is reached. Why??

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Check if you custom class recreate you UIView programmatically and doesn't throw away you storyboard xib

Comment: Can you verify that ViewController is loading. Make an IBOutlet and verify whether its alive or not?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem once, So what I did in my UIView class I wrote my custom initializer which was as following:

```
-(id) initAndConfigure{
    if (![self.subviews count])
    {
        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSArray *loadedViews = [mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"YourNibName" owner:nil options:nil];
        PlayerControlView *loadedView = [loadedViews firstObject];

        loadedView.frame = self.frame;
        loadedView.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
        loadedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints;

        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints)
        {
            id firstItem = constraint.firstItem;
            if (firstItem == self)
            {
                firstItem = loadedView;
            }
            id secondItem = constraint.secondItem;
            if (secondItem == self)
            {
                secondItem = loadedView;
            }
            [loadedView addConstraint:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstItem
                                          attribute:constraint.firstAttribute
                                          relatedBy:constraint.relation
                                             toItem:secondItem
                                          attribute:constraint.secondAttribute
                                         multiplier:constraint.multiplier
                                           constant:constraint.constant]];
        }
        return loadedView;
    }
    [self configureView];
    return self;
}
```

`[self configureView]` function is used to configure other view items.

> This problem occurs when a UIView is made in .xib and if someone try
>   to use this view in some other .xib.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I'm not currently at my workspace but will try your solution later.